# How to get tables listed those are created today or within last couple of hours on beeline ?

Tags: hive, beeline

I'm using beeline and have no special administrative privilege. It's developers account. Is there any way where I can see list of tables those were created today under particular schema today or within last couple hours? Thank you. Please let me know if you need any further information, thanks again.

Comment: can you access you hive metastore?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure how to check if I have access to meta-store or not. Can you please share if you have any command to access meta-store. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do so is by querying your **'metastore'**. Since you don't know your 'metastore' credentials follow below mentioned way step by step.

**Step 1:** Find your metastore string : In your beeline/hive shell write this command **'set -v'**.
This command will produce hive properties. Scroll up or down to find these properties :

**javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

**javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=password**

**javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://hostName:port/databaseName?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true**

**javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=userName**

**STEP 2:** Connect to your database with the use of credentials given in property. As in my case it is Mysql so :

**mysql -u userName -h hostName -pPassword -Pport**

**STEP 3 :** **use databaseName;**

**STEP 4:** **select TBL_ID,TBL_NAME,from_unixtime(CREATE_TIME) from TBLS order by CREATE_TIME desc;**

you will get all tables created with deacreaing time of creation. You can further filter table list by editing query.

P.S : In my case metastore was Mysql so I wrote queries corresponding to that.
In your case it could be any other database. so you have to modify your queries according to that.

**Hope this helped**

Comment: thank you detail information, let me check and get back to you.